# Merge two pandas data frames with conservation

Tags: pandas, vectorization

I'm working with two distinct data frames, `AlphaDF` and `BetaDF`, each containing unique columns. My goal is to merge `AlphaDF` with data from `BetaDF`, keeping every row from `AlphaDF` and adding corresponding data from `BetaDF` where there's a match.

Here's the script I initially wrote:

```py
combined_rows = []
for index, alpha_row in AlphaDF.iterrows():
    match = False
    for b_index, beta_row in BetaDF.iterrows():
        if alpha_row["alpha_id"] == beta_row["beta_id"] and alpha_row['start_point'] >= beta_row['range_start'] and alpha_row['end_point'] <= beta_row['range_end']:
            match = True
            combined_rows.append(alpha_row.tolist() + beta_row.tolist())
            break

    if not match:
        combined_rows.append(alpha_row.tolist() + [np.nan] * len(BetaDF.columns))

merged_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(combined_rows, columns=AlphaDF.columns.tolist() + BetaDF.columns.tolist())
```

To optimize this, I tried vectorized operations in pandas:

```py
BetaDF = BetaDF.rename(columns={'beta_id': 'alpha_id'})
merged_dataframe = pd.merge(AlphaDF, BetaDF, how='left', on='alpha_id')

condition = (merged_dataframe['start_point'] >= merged_dataframe['range_start']) & (merged_dataframe['end_point'] <= merged_dataframe['range_end'])
merged_dataframe = merged_dataframe[condition]

merged_dataframe.fillna(np.nan, inplace=True)
```

However, this method doesn't preserve every row in `AlphaDF`. Here's a sample of the data frames:

AlphaDF:

```
alpha_id, start_point, end_point, reference, score, strand, feature_count, label, value1, value2, value3
A123, 1000, 1050, ref:A123:1000-1050, 0.75, +, 2, primary, NaN, NaN, NaN
A124, 1070, 1100, ref:A124:1070-1100, 0.80, -, 1, secondary, NaN, NaN, NaN
...
```

BetaDF:

```
gene_id, alpha_id, range_start, range_end, orientation, is_partial, gene_type, data_version, data_source, gene_function, significance
101, A123, 950, 1075, forward, 0, coding, v1, SourceA, FunctionX, 0.05
102, A124, 1060, 1120, reverse, 1, non-coding, v1, SourceB, FunctionY, 0.03
...
```

Any suggestions on a more efficient and accurate approach using pandas operations to achieve this merging task?

Comment: Pls post a sample of your dataframes

Comment: @gtomer thank you for the suggestion, examples have been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `merged_dataframe[condition]` does not have all AlphaDF rows meeting the condition.

You can first merge and , set all BetaDF columns to empty values using `~condition` opposite.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)  
pd.options.display.expand_frame_repr = False

BetaDF = BetaDF.rename(columns={'beta_id': 'alpha_id'})
merged_dataframe = pd.merge(AlphaDF, BetaDF, how='left', on='alpha_id')


condition = ((merged_dataframe['start_point'] >= merged_dataframe['range_start']) &
             (merged_dataframe['end_point'] <= merged_dataframe['range_end']))

merged_dataframe.loc[~condition, BetaDF.columns[0]:] = np.nan

print(merged_dataframe)
```

**Update**: Removed the second option since 'beta_id' and 'alpha_id' may be on different rows.